# Dust file doesn't open in Webstorm IDE 8.0.5

Tags: webstorm, dust.js

I am trying to open a Dust (.dust) file in WebStorm but it doesn't open. I also installed Dust Plugin from WebStorm Plugin repository but I still can't open a Dust file. I am using WebStorm 8.0.5.

I also tried to open Dust with File -> Open option but I got an error saying "File of this type can't be opened in WebStorm"?

Can someone please help with this?

Comment: This is a problem with the plugin, and not Webstorm. I'd suggest contacting the creator.

Comment: Questions requesting help with third-party software should be directed to the creator of the software

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, guys! In the past I have found many answers about Eclipse/WebStorm on StackOverflow which were very useful so thought of asking this question here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now I can open Dust files in WebStorm IDE. All I had to do is add a plugin for Dust support and then update plugin configuration to support *.dust file.

Here are the steps:

- On your WebStorm (Mac version), click on Preferences -> Plugins.
- Click Browse Repositories, search for Dust. Click Install Plugin on right side frame of Dust Plugin.
- Restart your IDE.
- Open Preferences -> File Types
- Select Dust Templating Language.
- Edit Registered Patterns and add *.dust besides *.tl
- Apply the changes and now you should be able to open Dust files with proper IDE support for syntax and color highlighting in WebStorm.